# Laravelでリレーション先(hasMany)の情報を利用し絞り込み

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

・users_table
・posts_table
という２つのテーブルがあり、user has many postsの関係です。

usersは、id・name
postsは、id・user_id・content・created_at
のカラムを持っています。

そこで、２０１８年9月３日以降に投稿したユーザを取得したいと考えました。

```
    $user = User::with(['posts' => function($query){
        $query->where('created_at', '>', '2018-09-03');
    }])->get();
    dd($user);
```

・User.php

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

・users_tableの中身
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

・posts_tableの中身
[image: 'postsテーブル']
9月3日以降に投稿したユーザはuser_idが１または、３のユーザですので
dd($user)では、user1・user3が取得される予定ですが、三人とも取得されてしまいます。

リレーション先の情報を元に、絞り込むにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

[追記]

```
    $user = User::whereHas('posts', function($query){
        $query->where('created_at', '>', '2018-09-03');
    });
```

を利用することによって、解決しましたが、whereHasでできて、eager loadでできないのは何故
なのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereHas` はサブクエリを用いてリレーションを用いたSQLを発行します。追記にある通り、今回の目的ではこれを用いるが正解です。

一方、eager loadというのは先に取得したModelのコレクションに対して **あとからリレーションの取得** を行います。ここで指定できるクエリはメインのクエリ(ここではユーザー)に影響を与えることはなく、その**リレーション(post)を絞り込む**だけです。

(日本語訳ドキュメントをもう一度読んでみてください [Eloquent：リレーション#Eagerロード](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.6/ja/eloquent-relationships.html#eager-loading))

Comment: 後からリレーションの取得を行うのでしょうか？私は事前にリレーションの情報を取得しておく事で、N+1問題を解決していると理解してしまいました。@foreach($user->posts as $post){{$post->content}}@endforeachでは、$user->postsの段階でリレーションを毎度取得(後から取得)しているためN+1問題が発生する。つまりEageロードで事前にリレーション情報まで取得していればN+1問題を解決する(クエリの発行を１回で済ませる)のでは無いでしょうか？

Comment: Eager loadを用いれば（使うよりも先に）まとめてリレーションを引っ張ってこれるのでN+1問題が解決できるという認識は問題ありませんが、 ** クエリの発行を１回で済ませる** というのがある種の誤解なのかも。eager loadを用いたリレーションの取得の場合、リレーションはinを用いた追加のクエリで取得し(これが回答に示した「あとから」)、キーでマッピングされます。そのためこの例ではクエリは2つ発行されることになります。なのでおそらく本当に求めていることは `whereHas` と `with` を両方用いたクエリではないでしょうか。

Comment: とてもよく理解できました。コメントの追加で感謝を言うことは適切ではないと書いて有りますが、ありがとうございました。